# Discord.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm getting this error

```
.addField("Among Us related commands",
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

when using the help command i'm making which views info about commands i tried to check what's wrong with my code but didn't find any problems please help

```js
        const data = [];
        const { commands } = message.client;

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setAuthor(`My prefix here is ${prefix}\nuse ${prefix}help <command name> to get info about a command`);
         .addField("Among Us related commands",
         "tips");
         .addField("Among Us Mini Game",
         "soon");
         .addField("Utility commands",
         "ping");
         .setColor('GREEN');
         .setTimestamp();
         .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());

        const name = args[0]
        const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name))

        if(!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(embed)
        }

        const helpembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setTitle(`${command.name} command`)
         .addField("Description", command.desciption)
         .addField("Aliases", command.aliases || "none")
         .addField("Usage", command.usage || "none")
         .addFIeld("Example", command.example || "none")
         .setTimestamp()
         .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, member.author.avatarURL())

        message.channel.send(helpembed)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [function chaining](https://medium.com/technofunnel/javascript-function-chaining-8b2fbef76f7f), you need to remove the semicolons between the functions:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  // ...
  .setTimestamp(); // ; needs to be removed
  .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
```

Final result:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(`My prefix here is ${prefix}\nuse ${prefix}help <command name> to get info about a command`)
  .addField("Among Us related commands", "tips")
  .addField("Among Us Mini Game", "soon")
  .addField("Utility commands", "ping")
  .setColor('GREEN')
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
```